# Why isn't my user login logic working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform, authentication

I am attempting a simple user login using parse and javascript/jQuery. here's the html structure:

```
    <div class="login">
      <form class="user-pass">
        <input type="text" id="username-log" placeholder="username" maxlength="38">
        <input type="password" id="password-log" placeholder="password">
        <a href="#" id="pass-reset">Forgot Your Password?</a>
        <input type="submit" id="logBtn" value="Log In">
      </form>
    </div>
```

and here is the logic i am attempting to use:

```
    <script>
      Parse.initialize("LotjQTmAjiCVc26g2sk7XFz9c70n67KdfV3yxQ5Q", "JTL6gc7TCNwaTnKMx9fdZUlfKmRtyA1YXUy89cxK");

      $("#logBtn").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var userName = $("#username-log").val();
        var passWord = $("#password-log").val();

        Parse.User.logIn(userName, passWord, {
          success: function(user){
            console.log("Log in was a success!");
          }, error: function(user, error){
            console.log("Log in error:"+error.message);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

When i select the submit button, my page just refreshes and nothing comes to the console log. I have no prior experience with `.preventDefault` but isn't it supposed to prevent that? What seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the submit-event on the submit-input. That is not possible. The jquery-documentation says:

> "The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to
>   submit a form. It can ONLY be attached to form elements."

So try this instead:

```
$(".user-pass").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Or `$("#logBtn").click(...)`

Comment: hey so, it works sporadically. Every now and then it would create a session token  successfully, but more times than not it would shoot me an api error.. is it something I'm doing or is it parse?

Comment: Based on my very limited experience of Parse, the code looks alright. But maybe try asking another question and mention Parse in the title to get someone more qualified to take a look.